# How to count columns with the same value in a specific row in Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to count the number of columns that have a specific value (1) in a specific row (250). The value of the row is variable according to the query.

**I tried the code below, but it didn't work.**

```php
$total_r = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM registers WHERE ID = '$ID' AND 1 IN (column1, column2, column3, column4)";
$total = mysqli_num_rows($total_r);
echo $total;
```

I need the result as a number, lets say "2 columns" or something like that.

Comment: You should provide and some DB data also.

Comment: `SELECT ( (column1 = 1) + (column2 = 1) + …) AS total FROM registers WHERE ID = '$ID'` (minus the possible SQL injection part where `$ID` gets inserted, of course.)

Comment: Can the value ever be `NULL`?

Comment: How do I print the result. If I use echo, gives me an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally did was a general query and then fetch and save every column value into a variable. Then i just added them, because the value of each column could be 0 or 1. Here is the code:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM registers WHERE ID = '$ID'");
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$column1 = $result['column1'];
$column2 = $result['column2'];
$column3 = $result['column3'];

$total = $column1 + $column2 + $column3;
```

If the column has a value = 0, will not be considered into the count.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL Booleans become 0 or 1 in numerical context. So you could add expressions checking for a column to be equal to 1.

```
SELECT (column1 = 1)
       + (column2 = 1)
       + (column3 = 1)
       + (column4 = 1)
       FROM registers
       WHERE id = ?;
```

Comment: How do I print the result? When I use echo send me an error. Im using this: $total = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT (column1=1)+(column2=1)+(column3)=1 FROM registers WHERE ID = '$ID'");

Answer (score 0):

Check with below query

SELECT COUNT(*) TOT FROM registers WHERE ID = '$ID' AND column1='1' AND column2='1' AND column3='1' AND column4='1'

Answer (score 0):

What about:

> ```
> $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM registers WHERE ID = '$ID'");
> $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
>
> $columns_with_value_1 = array_count_values($result)[1];
> ```